# Android search list, String

Tags: java, android, list, search

Hey guys what is the best way to search through my list of objects, they return a few strings, last name and first name for example.

Here how i'm currently searching but my search needs to match the entire string which I don't want. The search needs it to match part of the string like our contacts list on our phone and ignore the case.

```
if (searchQ.equalsIgnoreCase(child.first_name)) {
   addChildToList(child); 
    }
```

Ive tried contains and starts with for example, they did not work. Whats going on?

Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: use textwatcher on edittext and getFilter() on adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TextWatcher to search in a list, as an example you define a TextWatcher for an EditText(search box) in this way :

```
TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() { //TextWatcher to Filter RealTime Input Data
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
            {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before,int count)   //Filter Data When Entering Data On ItemType Dialog TextView
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
            {   
            }
        };

        EditText filterText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtItemFilter);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

then in onTextChange() callback function you can send inserted characters as parameter s to your adapter to filter your List with getFilter or setup your list with filtered Cursor :

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before,int count)
        {
            ListView lv = getListView();
            ListAdapter adapter = (ListAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Hey great answer! Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using text watcher. My question was how should I do the search to compare the strings so they can be found with just a few letters of the string like contains

Comment: if i understand you well, you can use your string(s in textwatcher) and send it to your list adapter(your list query) and with like %your% statement in your query to filter that to selection which contains your String.

Comment: another solution would be writing getFilter method from the scratch and send your s in TextWatcher to getFilter and check it with desired data contains() function and if your desired data contains inputed String add it to an ArrayList,(its a bit complicated to mention in comments)